# iframe content body text return empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to get `iframe` content as text :

```
 var OCRTextframe='<iframe id="ocrtext" align="middle" src="http://localhost:...."/>';                    
 OCRText.innerHTML=OCRTextframe;
 var myIFrameBody = jQuery(document.getElementById('ocrtext')).contents().find('body').text();
 console.log("iframe body text : "+myIFrameBody.length);
```

my `iframe` was loaded successfully but  `myIFrameBody` is empty string with 0 length , did I miss something?

I tried implementing on load handler but in vain:

```
$('#ocrtext').load(function(){

            var myIFrameBody = $(this).contents().find('body').text();
            console.log("iframe body text : "+myIFrameBody);
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `jQuery(document.getElementById('ocrtext'))` wtf? Why not `#ocrtext` ?

Comment: it is within ajax query success function

Comment: try using `filter()` instead of `find()`

Comment: @charlietfl same result !

Comment: must be in load handler, need to make sure contents are rendered first,same result there?

Comment: also, to be clear, this is on same domain, port, protocol etc as page?

Comment: the on load event have not been triggered at all IDK why (am using Drupal btw)

Comment: emm not the same port , so how can I get it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the src after you attach the handler

```
var OCRTextframe = '<iframe id="ocrtext" align="middle" />';
OCRText.innerHTML = OCRTextframe;

var ocrTextDocument = jQuery(document.getElementById('ocrtext'))
ocrTextDocument.on("load", function () {
    var myIFrameBody = ocrTextDocument.contents().find('body').text();
    console.log("iframe body text : " + myIFrameBody.length);
})
ocrTextDocument.attr("src", "http://localhost:....")
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I gave it a try but it seems that is  a security issue like @charlietfl said : `Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:8888". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`